# How to binding only single class when using several v-on:click?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm newbie and studying Vue.js
I create v-on:click function and  element toggle class when I click the button.

I am not good at English, I think it will be fast to show the code.

```html
<button @click="bindA = !bindA">A</button>
<button @click="bindB = !bindB">B</button>

<span :class="[{ classA:bindA }, { classB:bindB }]"></span>
```

```js
data: function() {
  return {
    bindA: true, // default
    bindB: false
}
```

it's now. clicked bindA and B.

```html
// browser
<span class="classA classB"></span>
```

but I want

```html
// bindA click , remove classB
<span class="classA"></span>

// bindB click , remove classA
<span class="classB"></span>
```

It's simple in jquery, but difficult in vue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a method to the `@click` - then you can build up a more complex logic, than simple "toggle".

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    bindA: true,
    bindB: false
  },
  methods: {
    bind(btn) {
      if ((btn === 'A' && !this.bindA) || (btn === 'B' && !this.bindB)) {
        this.bindA = !this.bindA
        this.bindB = !this.bindB
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="bind('A')">A</button>
  <button @click="bind('B')">B</button>

  <span :class="{ classA:bindA, classB:bindB }"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: data should return a function ;)

Comment: Nope - only in single file components. Data returns a function, because that ensures that the component is separate from the other instances of the same component. If we have only one (the Vue instance), then it is an object.

Comment: That's why we all are here on SO :D

Comment: And actually not only in single file components, but in components in generally - https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html :)

Comment: Yeah! I did check the docs, I had he misconception that not returning a function messed with reactivity, but you are right, it’s only for reusable components, in the example above in particular there should be only one App in the dom

Comment: Actually it's because an object is a reference to bits in memory, and the copy of the object has the reference to the same bits - change the referenced bits, and you modify all the references. A function is different, it has its own "map" in the memory. (Or something like this :D)

Comment: It works perfectly.  I think it can be applied. Thank you :)

Comment: That makes a lot of sense!

Comment: @Jeon I'm happy that I could help! :)

Answer (score 2):

It's very simple in vue as well.
Bind the class according to the conditions you want to see the data

```
  :class="{'classA': (bindA== true), 'classB':(bindA== false)}"
```

Comment: the `bindA == true` is not necesary. `:class="{ 'classA': bindA, 'classB': bindB }"` is enough

Comment: This solution is toggling classes by clicking either buttons. This was not the question, as I understood - class A should be added if btnA is clicked, but not if btnB and vice versa. So it's one step more complicated than this.